# PHP $_SESSION getting PHP Notice: Undefined index

Tags: php, pdo

I have the following PHP code which gets data from SQL via PDO:

```
  $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $tableName = 'categories';

    ob_start();
    session_start(); 


    //Get values from table
    $sqlprimaryCategory = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tableName GROUP BY primary_category");
    $sqlprimaryCategory->execute();
    echo '<form id="form1" action="" method="post">';
    echo '<select name="primary_category" size = "4" onChange="document.getElementById(\'form1\').submit();"> ';
    while ($resultprimary = $sqlprimaryCategory->fetch()) {
        echo '<option value="';
        echo $resultprimary['primary_category'];
        echo '">';
        echo $resultprimary['primary_category'];
        echo '</option>'; 
    }
    echo '</select>'; 
    //echo '<input type="submit" name="primary_category_button" id="primary_category_button" value="Submit">';
    echo '</form>'; 


    if (isset($_POST['primary_category'])) {
        $_SESSION['primary_category'] = $_POST['primary_category'];
        //unset($_SESSION['secondary_category']);
        //unset($_SESSION['tertiary_category']);

    }

    //Get values from table
    $sqlSecondaryCategory = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE primary_category = :primary_category GROUP BY secondary_category");
    $sqlSecondaryCategory->execute(array(':primary_category'=>$_SESSION['primary_category']));
    echo '<form id="form2" action="" method="post">';
    echo '<select name="secondary_category" size = "4" onChange="document.getElementById(\'form2\').submit();"> ';
    while ($resultSecondary = $sqlSecondaryCategory->fetch()) {
        echo '<option value="';
        echo $resultSecondary['secondary_category'];
        echo '">';
        echo $resultSecondary['secondary_category'];
        echo '</option>'; 
    }
    echo '</select>'; 
    //echo '<input type="submit" name="secondary_category_button" id="secondary_category_button" value="Submit">';
    echo '</form>'; 


    if (isset($_POST['secondary_category'])) {
        $_SESSION['secondary_category'] = $_POST['secondary_category'];
        //unset($_SESSION['tertiary_category']);

    }


    //Get values from table
    $sqlTertiaryCategory = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE secondary_category = :secondary_category GROUP BY tertiary_category");
    $sqlTertiaryCategory->execute(array(':secondary_category'=>$_SESSION['secondary_category']));
    echo '<form id="form3" action="" method="post">';
    echo '<select name="tertiary_category" size = "4" onChange="document.getElementById(\'form3\').submit();"> ';
    while ($resultSecondary = $sqlTertiaryCategory->fetch()) {
        echo '<option value="';
        echo $resultSecondary['tertiary_category'];
        echo '">';
        echo $resultSecondary['tertiary_category'];
        echo '</option>'; 
    }
    echo '</select>'; 
    //echo '<input type="submit" name="tertiary_category_button" id="tertiary_category_button" value="Submit">';
    echo '</form>'; 


    if (isset($_POST['tertiary_category'])) {
        $_SESSION['tertiary_category'] = $_POST['tertiary_category'];
        unset($_SESSION['tertiary_category']);

    }





    if (isset($_POST['primary_category']) OR isset($_POST['secondary_category']) OR isset($_POST['tertiary_category'])) {
        echo $_SESSION['primary_category'];
        echo $_SESSION['secondary_category'];
        echo $_SESSION['tertiary_category'];
    }
```

The above is a drop-down menu. The second html dropdown shows the content based on the selection of the first selection, while the thrid dropdown shows the content based on the selection of the second dropdown. How can I fix my code to remove the error?

Comment: Is it `$_POST['secondary_category']` or `$_SESSION['secondary_category']`? Your first snippet shows `$_POST` but your larger snippet shows `$_SESSION`.

Comment: It is $_SESSION['secondary_category'] I ammended it in my question

Comment: I don't see your `session_start()`. Did you remember to put it at the top of your page?

Comment: @JohnConde most probably if he is using `$_SESSION['primary_category']`

Comment: I posted the full code in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If second category isn't posted it's not in the `session`, so you won't be able to access it.

You can fix it checking if `$_SESSION['secondary_category']` isset before using it in your third request statement

```
if (isset($_POST['secondary_category'])) {
    $_SESSION['secondary_category'] = $_POST['secondary_category'];
    unset($_SESSION['tertiary_category']);
}elseif (!isset($_SESSION['secondary_category'])){
    $_SESSION['secondary_category'] = null;
}
```

Comment: Why the -1 for  $_SESSION['secondary_category'] = -1; couldn't it be null instead?

Comment: no. Null is nothing. If it's null the key doesn't exist. It's not set. Actually setting something to null is like using the `unset()` function on it. And -1 because obviously no category will have this id, so your mysql request will return nothing. It's still a hack, you'd rather check for the existence of the key, and do or not your mysql request accordingly.

Comment: I replaced your -1 (since it is being echoed) with null and it seems that your code worked fine - no errors are being displayed.

Comment: My bad, the key actually still exist, but `isset` will return false for that key. So yeah, you are good setting the session secondary_category to null.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['tertiary_category'])) {
    $_SESSION['tertiary_category'] = $_POST['tertiary_category'];
    //unset($_SESSION['tertiary_category']); < why unset right after assigning? (COMMENT OUT)

}




//Change OR's to AND's because the echo's will only work if all of them are set.
if (isset($_POST['primary_category']) AND isset($_POST['secondary_category']) AND isset($_POST['tertiary_category'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['primary_category'];
    echo $_SESSION['secondary_category'];
    echo $_SESSION['tertiary_category'];
}
// If you want to print out the ones that exist, make separate if statements for each category to see if they exist, or give them a blank value instead of unsetting them.
```